# "Run user flow" button does not appear in Microsoft Entra External ID

Tags: microsoft-entra-id, microsoft-entra-external-id

I followed Microsoft Entra ID's documentation to create a web API and an SPA and both of them redirect the requests to URLs like `https://jwt.ms` and `http://localhost:4200`. I also created a user flow by following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/how-to-test-user-flows) and associated the SPA application with the user flow. According to the documentation, the "Run user flow" document should appear after a few minutes but never shows up and hence I'm unable to produce a token.

Assuming all tutorial steps are followed carefully, what is the issue in this setup? Is there anything that's not possibly documented or missing?

Comment: It doesn't appear on my customer tenant either. I run the application attached to the user flow to get a token.

Comment: I do not see it either. I reported this internally to check. I will update you guys once I have more details.

Answer (score 0):

It works now as expected, it was solved by Microsoft team:

[image]